# How to use ray in a docker swarm

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm, ray

I'm trying to set up a cluster with one ray-head and two ray-workers with docker swarm. I have three machines for this, one running the ray-had and two each one ray-worker. The cluster comes up ok, but whenever i exec into a container and run:

```
import ray
ray.init(redis-address='ray-head:6379')
```

i get

```
WARNING worker.py:1274 -- Some processes that the driver needs to connect to have not registered with Redis, so retrying. Have you run 'ray start' on this node?
```

The logs of the containers looḱ ok.

I have also with IPs as well, both the machine and the ip of the ray-head container.

```
ray.init(redis-address='192.168.30.193:6379')
```

When running:

```
telnet 192.168.30.193 6379
```

there is an answer.

Dockerfile for the containers:

```
FROM python:2.7-slim

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    libxml2 \
    gcc \
    vim \
    iputils-ping \
    telnet \
    procps \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN pip install ray

CMD ["echo", "Base Image Ready"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  ray-head:
    image: simpled:0.1
    shm_size: '2gb'
    entrypoint: [ '/usr/local/bin/ray']
    command: ['start', '--head', '--redis-port', '6379', '--redis-shard-ports','6380,6381', '--object-manager-port','12345', '--node-manager-port','12346', '--node-ip-address', 'ray-head', '--block']
    ports:
      - target: 6379
        published: 6379
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 6380
        published: 6380
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 6381
        published: 6381
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 12345
        published: 12345
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 12346
        published: 12346
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.Head == true ]
  ray-worker:
    image: simpled:0.1
    shm_size: '2gb'
    entrypoint: [ '/usr/local/bin/ray']
    command: ['start', '--node-ip-address', 'ray-worker', '--redis-address', 'ray-head:6379', '--object-manager-port', '12345', '--node-manager-port', '12346', '--block']
    ports:
      - target: 12345
        published: 12345
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 12346
        published: 12346
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    depends_on:
      - "ray-head"
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.Head != true]
```

Am i doing it wrong? Anyone that have gotten it to work in swarm mode.

*EDIT 2019-04-14*

Log of head:

```
[root@ray-node-1 bd-migratie-core]# docker service logs qaudt0j3clfv
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:34,187  INFO scripts.py:288 -- Using IP address 10.0.30.2 for this node.
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:34,190  INFO node.py:423 -- Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49-34_1/logs.
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:34,323  INFO services.py:363 -- Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:6379 to respond...
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:34,529  INFO services.py:363 -- Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:6380 to respond...
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:34,538  INFO services.py:760 -- Starting Redis shard with 0.74 GB max memory.
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:34,704  INFO services.py:363 -- Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:6381 to respond...
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:34,714  INFO services.py:760 -- Starting Redis shard with 0.74 GB max memory.
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:34,859  WARNING services.py:1261 -- WARNING: The object store is using /tmp instead of /dev/shm because /dev/shm has only 67108864 bytes available. This may slow down performance! You may be able to free up space by deleting files in /dev/shm or terminating any running plasma_store_server processes. If you are inside a Docker container, you may need to pass an argument with the flag '--shm-size' to 'docker run'.
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:34,862  INFO services.py:1384 -- Starting the Plasma object store with 1.11 GB memory using /tmp.
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:34,997  INFO scripts.py:319 -- 
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | Started Ray on this node. You can add additional nodes to the cluster by calling
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    |     ray start --redis-address 10.0.30.2:6379
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | from the node you wish to add. You can connect a driver to the cluster from Python by running
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    |     import ray
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    |     ray.init(redis_address="10.0.30.2:6379")
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | If you have trouble connecting from a different machine, check that your firewall is configured properly. If you wish to terminate the processes that have been started, run
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    | 
simpled_ray-head.1.n5ajmtfoftmw@ray-node-1.bidirection.se    |     ray stop
```

ps aux inside head container:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.2  1.9 289800 70860 ?        Ss   17:49   0:01 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ray start --head --redis-port 6379 --redis-shard-ports 6380,6381 --object-manager-port 12345 --node-manager-port 12346 --node-ip-addres
root         9  0.9  1.4 182352 50920 ?        Rl   17:49   0:05 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/thirdparty/redis/src/redis-server *:6379
root        14  0.8  1.3 182352 48828 ?        Rl   17:49   0:04 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/thirdparty/redis/src/redis-server *:6380
root        18  0.5  1.4 188496 52320 ?        Sl   17:49   0:03 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/thirdparty/redis/src/redis-server *:6381
root        22  3.1  1.9 283144 70132 ?        S    17:49   0:17 /usr/local/bin/python -u /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/monitor.py --redis-address=10.0.30.2:6379
root        23  0.7  0.0  15736  1852 ?        S    17:49   0:04 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet_monitor 10.0.30.2 6379
root        25  0.0  0.0 1098804 1528 ?        S    17:49   0:00 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/core/src/plasma/plasma_store_server -s /tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49-34_1/sockets/plasma_store -m 1111605657 -d /tmp
root        26  0.5  0.0  32944  2524 ?        Sl   17:49   0:03 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet /tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49-34_1/sockets/raylet /tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49-34_1/sockets/p
root        27  1.1  0.9 246340 35192 ?        S    17:49   0:06 /usr/local/bin/python -u /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/log_monitor.py --redis-address=10.0.30.2:6379 --logs-dir=/tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49-34_1/logs
root        31  2.7  0.9 385800 35368 ?        Sl   17:49   0:15 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/workers/default_worker.py --node-ip-address=10.0.30.2 --object-store-name=/tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49
root        32  2.7  0.9 385800 35364 ?        Sl   17:49   0:15 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/workers/default_worker.py --node-ip-address=10.0.30.2 --object-store-name=/tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49
root        48  2.2  0.0  19944  2232 pts/0    Ss   17:59   0:00 bash
root        53  0.0  0.0  38376  1644 pts/0    R+   17:59   0:00 ps aux
```

Log of worker:

```
simpled_ray-worker.0.n0t4roion9h2@ray-node-2.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:35,716        INFO services.py:363 -- Waiting for redis server at 10.0.30.2:6379 to respond...
simpled_ray-worker.0.n0t4roion9h2@ray-node-2.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:35,733        INFO scripts.py:363 -- Using IP address 10.0.30.5 for this node.
simpled_ray-worker.0.n0t4roion9h2@ray-node-2.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:35,748        INFO node.py:423 -- Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49-35_1/logs.
simpled_ray-worker.0.n0t4roion9h2@ray-node-2.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:35,794        WARNING services.py:1261 -- WARNING: The object store is using /tmp instead of /dev/shm because /dev/shm has only 67108864 bytes available. This may slow down performance! You may be able to free up space by deleting files in /dev/shm or terminating any running plasma_store_server processes. If you are inside a Docker container, you may need to pass an argument with the flag '--shm-size' to 'docker run'.
simpled_ray-worker.0.n0t4roion9h2@ray-node-2.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:35,796        INFO services.py:1384 -- Starting the Plasma object store with 1.11 GB memory using /tmp.
simpled_ray-worker.0.n0t4roion9h2@ray-node-2.bidirection.se    | 2019-04-14 17:49:35,894        INFO scripts.py:371 -- 
simpled_ray-worker.0.n0t4roion9h2@ray-node-2.bidirection.se    | Started Ray on this node. If you wish to terminate the processes that have been started, run
simpled_ray-worker.0.n0t4roion9h2@ray-node-2.bidirection.se    | 
simpled_ray-worker.0.n0t4roion9h2@ray-node-2.bidirection.se    |     ray stop
```

ps aux of worker:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.1  1.9 292524 70900 ?        Ss   17:49   0:01 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ray start --node-ip-address ray-worker --redis-address ray-head:6379 --object-manager-port 12345 --node-manager-port 12346 --block
root        10  0.0  0.0 1098804 1532 ?        S    17:49   0:00 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/core/src/plasma/plasma_store_server -s /tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49-35_1/sockets/plasma_store -m 1111605657 -d /tmp
root        11  0.5  0.0  32944  2520 ?        Sl   17:49   0:04 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/core/src/ray/raylet/raylet /tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49-35_1/sockets/raylet /tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49-35_1/sockets/p
root        12  0.8  0.9 246320 35192 ?        S    17:49   0:06 /usr/local/bin/python -u /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/log_monitor.py --redis-address=10.0.30.2:6379 --logs-dir=/tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49-35_1/logs
root        15  2.7  0.9 385800 35368 ?        Sl   17:49   0:19 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/workers/default_worker.py --node-ip-address=10.0.30.5 --object-store-name=/tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49
root        16  2.7  0.9 385800 35360 ?        Sl   17:49   0:19 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ray/workers/default_worker.py --node-ip-address=10.0.30.5 --object-store-name=/tmp/ray/session_2019-04-14_17-49
root        39  4.5  0.0  19944  2236 pts/0    Ss   18:01   0:00 bash
root        44  0.0  0.0  38376  1648 pts/0    R+   18:01   0:00 ps aux
```

EDIT 2019-04-17

I know the reason why it doesn't work now, but not how to fix it.

If i log into the head container and check the ip where the ray processes are running

```
ray/monitor.py --redis-address=10.0.30.5:6379
```

This matches

```
/# ping ray-head
PING ray-head (10.0.30.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.30.5 (10.0.30.5): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms
```

But it doesn't match

```
/hostname -i
10.0.30.6
```

If i move the ray processes to start with --redis-address=10.0.30.6:6379
it works.

Comment: Well, the error says to run `ray start`. Have you done that?

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not the Ray processes are running on each node? E.g., if you connect to one node and do something like `ps aux | grep ray`, do you see a bunch of Ray processes that are alive? From each node (head and worker nodes), can you connect directly to Redis? E.g., in python try `import redis; r = redis.StrictRedis(host='ray-head', port=6379); r.set('key', 'value')`, does that work? One possible thing that could be going wrong is that Ray is confusing the pod IP address and the physical machine IP address.

Comment: @samthegolden Yes, 'ray start' is run via the 'docker stack deploy' command. I have edited the original post with ps and log output.

Comment: @RobertNishihara Thank you for answering. I have appended the output from docker service log and ps aux in the containers. I also tried your redis test on one worker:
    >>> import redis 
    >>> r = redis.StrictRedis(host='ray-head', port=6379)
    >>> r.set('key', 'value')
    True
    >>> r.get('key')
    'value'

It looks like directly calling redis is working.

Comment: Two questions (for debugging): 1) Does `ray.init(redis_address='10.0.30.2:6379')` work (on the worker nodes or on the head node? 2) Does `ray.init(redis_address='localhost:6379')` work on the head node? It seems like Ray wants to use the address `10.0.30.2` based on the commands used to start the processes (as shown by `ps`). This may be an issue of Ray not using the right IP address when inside of a container or something like that.

Comment: @RobertNishihara No, neither of the commands work. I cannot get ray.init from worker or head with either 'ip' or 'ray-head', or 'localhost' in the case of head, to work. Although if i run the redis code you posted earlier that works for all cases. If i run 'ping ray-head' from the worker container it resolve correctly to 10.0.30.2

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to fix it:

The hostname of the ray-head container is NOT 'ray-head', but 'tasks.ray-head'.

To make it work i needed to change the hostnames inside the docker-compose files like this:

For ray-head:

```
command: ['start', '--head', '--redis-port', '6379', '--redis-shard-ports','6380,6381', '--object-manager-port','12345', '--node-manager-port','12346', '--node-ip-address', 'tasks.ray-head', '--block']
```

For ray-worker:

```
command: ['start', '--redis-address', 'tasks.ray-head:6379', '--object-manager-port', '12345', '--node-manager-port', '12346', '--block']
```

Now i can run this on any host:

```
ray.init('tasks.ray-head:6379')
```

I hope this helps someone else in the same situation